# If $ (a_n) $ is a sequence s.t. for every integer $ p > 1 $ . $ ( a_{pk} )_{k=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow L $ , then $ (a_n) \rightarrow L $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples

**Prove/Disprove:** If $ ( a_n) $ is a sequence s.t. for every integer $ p > 1 $ the subsequence $ ( a_{pk} )_{k=1}^{\infty} $ converges to the same limit, then $ (a_n) $ converges to the same limit.

**Answer:** The statement's false. Take for example the sequence
$ \begin{aligned}
a_n=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }n  \text{ is prime } \\
0 & \text{else }n \text{ is not prime } \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$

**My question**: The sequence above is one such counter-example, but I still have quite difficulty understanding it. Maybe you can please elaborate more on why this subsequence provides a counter-example? does there exists an easier counter-example than above?

Comment: Note that for all $p,k>1$, $pk$ is not prime

Comment: The first element of every sequence $ (pk)_{k=1}^{\infty} $ is either prime or not. since we have infinite index sequences like these for every $ p>1 $ then the partial limits of $ a_n 
$ are  $+1$ ( this is for all indexes $ pk $ that are prime ) and $0$ ( incase the indexes are not prime ).

Comment: Well, that is a prime number? Is $pk$ ever prime?

Comment: No, $ pk $ is prime infinitely often for $ k=1 $ and for all $ p>1 $ , so we can choose those indexes $ p \cdot 1 $ ( for k=1) which are prime and for them we will get $ 0 $ as a partial limit for $ (a_n) $

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Using the definitions given in my answer can you conclude ?

Comment: We conclude that the given example for sequence is indeed a counter-example since we can choose infinite indexs from $ (p \cdot 1 ) $ [ k = 1 ] for which the index is a prime and we can also choose infinite indexes from $ ( pk) $ for $ p,k > 1 $ for which the index sequences are not prime.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Yes and form there you can conclude that it does not converge

Comment: @hazelnut_116 does my answer answer your question?

Comment: @VivaanDaga If you could add some of the things we wrote here in the comments then I'll accept it because if It weren't for these comments I wouldn't immediately understand why the given sequence is a counter-example.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a sequence $a_{n}$ converges to $x\in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a natural $N$ such that for all naturals $n$ greater than $N$ $|a_{n}-x|<\epsilon$.
 If you want to prove that the sequence does not converge to any $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ , you have to prove the above statements negation that is ; for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an epsilon such that for all natural $N$ there exists a natural $n$ greater than $N$ such that $|a_{n}-x|>\epsilon$.
 Since the primes are  infinite you can easily conclude form here that your sequence does not converge but $a_{kp}$ does converge since $kp$ is never prime for all $k,p > 1$ .

Comment: @ArcticChar I thought p was also prime edited